# How to reduce color by predefined array in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-glide

I have an array of like 25 dominant colors from a picture in HEXcode [e1e1e1,333333,etc.etc.]
Now i want to use the array full of color codes with the image i have and reduce its colors to only have those dominant colors.

F.e. 
I have this image: https://marshallgrain.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/parrot.jpg?w=224&h=300
I want it to be like this:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Screen_color_test_VGA_16colors.png

Beside that i use Glide (http://glide.thephpleague.com/) to pixelate and resize/crop my image. And Thief(https://github.com/ksubileau/color-thief-php) for the palette. How do i use this with GD or does anyone has a better solution ? as i have no clue how to continue from this part to removing/replacing colors.

```
public function getImage($userDirectory, $imageId, $width=30, $height=30, $colors=25) {
    $scaler = 5;

    $w = ((int)$width >= 15) ? (int)$width * 4 : 60;
    $h = ((int)$height >= 15) ? (int)$height * 4 : 60;
    $c = ((int)$colors >= 1) ? (int)$colors : 25;

    $path = 'public/images/'.$userDirectory.'/'.$imageId.'.jpg';
    $palette = ColorThief::getPalette($path, $c);

    $options = ['w'=>$w*$scaler,'h'=>$h*$scaler,'fit'=>'crop','fm'=>'jpg','pixel'=>$scaler,'border'=>'5,000000,expand','mark'=>'logo.png','markx'=>5,'marky'=>5,'markpos'=>'top-left'];

    $server = ServerFactory::create([
        'watermarks' => 'public/images/'.$userDirectory,
        'source' => 'public/images/'.$userDirectory,
        'cache' => 'public/images/'.$userDirectory.'/.cache',
    ]);

    $server->outputImage($imageId.'.jpg', $options);
}
```

Comment: You need the following functionality: Loop through every pixel, calculate error between pixel color and every palette color, find the closest palette color based on the minimum error, replace pixel color by palette color. Which of these steps do you need help with?

Comment: That would be way to slow for large images, ive seen imagetruecolortopalette from gd which almost does what i need, but how to use the glide image in it ? Or is there any other fast way? Images can be resized with glide to any size so it must render fast. Maybe imagemagick but i have never used it nor understand how it works.

Comment: @SurudoiRyu you think `imagetruecolortopalette` or whatever function you find doesn't do exactly what @Matey described?

Comment: @bassxzero in the end maybe yes. Looping trough each pixel of an image like 3k X 3k pixels seems rather slow and resource intensive. I’ve made a look alike of what i wanna achieve on jsfiddle which just almost kills the browser with large images. https://jsfiddle.net/surudoiryu/4rgrpgyw/

Comment: @SurudoiRyu GD runs server side, so your fiddle killing the browser is irrelevant. How do you propose you figure out a pixel's color without looping through and testing it? You can't. O(n) is the best you're going to get on a fresh/unseen image. Also, 9k pixels each with a size of 3 bytes is not a lot.

Comment: @bassxzero true that, i know server side is faster. But im also looking for fastest way to render. ive seen the GD method, but maybe there is a more optimized library that could achieve it. Or is in your opinion just looping through the pixels and change it by closest color the best way ?

Comment: @SurudoiRyu I would try the looping through each pixel method first and see how bad it is. I would implement 1 optimization in your loop. Create a cache array/map of (pixel input values, pixel dominant color). Check to see if you have already found a pixel's dominant color so that you don't have to calculate it twice. This should help in most cases.

Comment: @bassxzero thanks will try it out, that last part is actually smart haven’t thought about that! When i got a working example ill show it.

Comment: There's no other way than looping through pixels. Even 3rd party implementations like imagemagick or GD have to do that. The difference is in code optimization, memory optimization and the inherent speed of the code execution. Obviously, native imagemagick implementation will be faster than interpreted PHP. The GD function `imagetruecolortopalette` does something close to what you need but unfortunately you can not specify the palette. Only the number of colors. The palette contents are determined inside the algorithm. I suggest you look into imagemagick, it's a very powerful tool.

Comment: @bassxzero got it working a bit still needs optimisation: www.customdiamondpainting.nl thanks for the help!